Nginx config rewrite .php working but forms broke
I am having trouble with the Nginx default config for my website. My PHP website runs on a linux azure machine, which uses nginx. This is currently my config:
server {
    #proxy_cache cache;
        #proxy_cache_valid 200 1s;
    listen 8080;
    listen [::]:8080;
    root /home/site/wwwroot;
    index  index.php;
    server_name  example.com www.example.com
    port_in_redirect off;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @extensionless-php;
    }

    # dont show /index, index.php
    if ( $request_uri ~ "/index" ) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/ $1/ permanent;
    }

    # remove .php from url
    if ($request_uri ~ \.php($|\?))
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
    }

    location @extensionless-php {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
    }

    # remove www. from url
    if ($host ~ '^www\.') {
        return 301 https://exmaple.com$request_uri;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /html/;
    }

    # Disable .git directory
    location ~ /\.git {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }

    # Add locations of phpmyadmin here.
    location ~* [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.[Pp][Hh][Pp])(|/.*)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout         300;
        fastcgi_send_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout           3600;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }
}

All I try to achieve is the following:

I want people to be able to go to mywebsite.com/register
1b. I want people to be able to go to mywebsite.com/register.php
The URL should ALWAYS look like mywebsite.com/register

This config does this! So I was happy. But I cheered too soon.
<form action="register.php" method="post"

Now my forms don't work anymore, when I click the register button the page just refreshes and does nothing. If I remove this part from the config:
# remove .php from url
    if ($request_uri ~ \.php($|\?))
    {
        rewrite ^(.*)\.php$ $1 permanent;
    }

The forms work again! But the .php is visible again in the URL. So my question is, what is wrong with my config and how can I achieve the things I described above?
